# Looking for a alternative to Power BI that can be hosted locally

Tags: business-intelligence

I have no interest in hosting my dashboards and reports in the cloud. Power BI Report Server sounds like what I need but not worth $5000/month.

Answer (score 1):

[Bold BI](https://www.boldbi.com) provides an On-Premise version that can host Dashboards and can be self hosted as per your needs. There is also a similar product for Reports [Bold Reports](https://www.boldreports.com).

Pricing starts at $395 per month for unlimited users and 10 creators.

Note: I work for Syncfusion (the company behind Bold BI and Bold Reports).